# Get GAC entries by Public Key

Tags: c#, assemblies, runtime, gac

Is there a way to scan all the assemblies in the GAC and return a list of names of assemblies with a specified Public Key Token during runtime?  I know the Public Key of all the GAC assemblies that I am interested in loading, but don't necessarily know the names or version numbers.

Comment: I believe you could try a `ReflectionOnlyLoad()` of every assembly in the GAC and filter the ones where the `FullName` property contains the public key token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time ago but I think the public key is part of the directory names where the assemblies are stored. So maybe you could just loop through all the subdirs in the *Assembly* folder and see if any of the sub dirs contains the public key.
Seem to remember that the sub dir format is something like `version_somethingIcan'tRemember_publicKey`.

If you don't already know, Windows Explorer hides the real layout of the *Assembly* folder but you can open a command prompt and CD into it. Just remember that any assemblies can be under any of multiple of the direct sub directories to the *Assembly* folder so probably safest to loop through all of them.

Comment: Thanks I'll try to create a custom AssemblyInfo object to build the full name I'll need to load the assembly.